# how does dot syntax work in objective c

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I'm trying to figure out if I can use  dot syntax in objective c in order to access class variables.

For example if I have a class named ClassA of type NSObject.

ClassA has an instance of a  class named ClassB also of type NSObject.

And ClassB has a variable named myString of type NSString;

In a view controller that has an instance of ClassA as a variable I'm trying to access "myString" by saying

```
NSString *aString=classA.classB.myString;
```

Which gives me this error

```
 error: accessing unknown 'myString' component of a property
```

if classB can be accessed with the dot syntax why can't the string variable?

///////////added edit//////////

Sorry for the delay.
Also the comment box only allows so many characters so I had to use the anser box instead.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class PromoTrackValueObject;
@class PromoMixValueObject;
@class PromoSkinValueObject;
@class EventsValueObject;
@class BuyValueObject;


@interface PromoValueObject : NSObject {
    NSString *promoXMLPath;
    NSString *type;
    NSString *username;
    NSString *entityname;
    NSString *userid;
    NSString *hasavatar;
    NSString *trackbuy_profile;
    NSString *bio;
    NSString *country;
    NSString *url_facebook;
    NSString *url_twitter;
    NSString *url_discog;
    NSString *url_myspace;
    NSString *url_chart;
    NSString *labelname;
    NSString *labelurl;
    NSString *labelimg;
    NSString *agent_name;
    NSString *agent_url;
    NSString *agent_img;
    NSString *promo_date;

    PromoTrackValueObject *promoTrack;
    PromoMixValueObject *promoMix;
    PromoSkinValueObject *promoSkin; // class containing string property in question is in here
    EventsValueObject *events;
    BuyValueObject *buy;



}

@property (nonatomic,copy)NSString *promoXMLPath;
@property (nonatomic,copy)NSString *type;
@property (nonatomic,copy)NSString *username;
@property (nonatomic,copy)NSString *entityname;
@property (nonatomic,copy)NSString *userid;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *hasavatar;
@property (nonatomic,copy)NSString *trackbuy_profile;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *bio;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *country;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *url_facebook;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *url_twitter;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *url_discog;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *url_myspace;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *url_chart;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *labelname;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *labelurl;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *labelimg;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *agent_name;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *agent_url;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *agent_img;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *promo_date;

@property(nonatomic,retain)PromoTrackValueObject *promoTrack;
@property(nonatomic,retain)PromoMixValueObject *promoMix;
@property(nonatomic,retain)PromoSkinValueObject *promoSkin;
@property(nonatomic,retain)EventsValueObject *events;
@property(nonatomic,retain)BuyValueObject *buy;
@end


#import "PromoValueObject.h"
@implementation PromoValueObject
@synthesize promoXMLPath;
@synthesize type;
@synthesize username;
@synthesize entityname;
@synthesize userid;
@synthesize hasavatar;
@synthesize trackbuy_profile;
@synthesize bio;
@synthesize country;
@synthesize url_facebook;
@synthesize url_twitter;
@synthesize url_discog;
@synthesize url_myspace;
@synthesize url_chart;
@synthesize labelname;
@synthesize labelurl;
@synthesize labelimg;
@synthesize agent_name;
@synthesize agent_url;
@synthesize agent_img;
@synthesize promoMix;
@synthesize promoSkin;
@synthesize events;
@synthesize buy;
@synthesize promoTrack;
@synthesize promo_date;

- (void)dealloc {
    [promoTrack release];
    [promoMix release];
    [promoSkin release];
    [events release];
    [buy release];
   [promoXMLPath release];
    [type release];
    [username release];
    [entityname release];
    [userid release];
    [hasavatar release];
    [trackbuy_profile release];
    [bio release];
    [country release];
    [url_facebook release];
    [url_twitter release];
    [url_discog release];
    [url_chart release];
    [labelname release];
    [labelurl release];
    [labelimg release];
    [agent_name release];
    [agent_url release];
    [agent_img release];
    [promo_date release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

@end

```
@interface PromoSkinValueObject : NSObject {

    NSString *promo_skin_url;  // the string I'm after
    NSString *promo_skin_id;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *promo_skin_url;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *promo_skin_id;


@end



   #import "PromoSkinValueObject.h"


    @implementation PromoSkinValueObject
    @synthesize promo_skin_url;
    @synthesize promo_skin_id;
    @end
```

//trying to add dot syntax here

This line of code is in a class which sytesizes promoValueObject

```
NSString *skin=promoValueObject.promoSkin.promo_skin_url;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dot syntax is designed to be an exactly precise synonym for method invocations to methods that play the setter/getter role.  To use the `.` [dot] syntax, the type of the object must be exactly specified and the object must implement the appropriate method.   Dot syntax is *not* used to somehow gain direct access to instance variables.

Thus, you say:

> And ClassB has a variable named
>   myString of type NSString;

And this is likely the problem.  You need to *either* define methods to access `myString` or declare a property and `@synthesize` the methods.  Either will work and both are effectively equivalent (save for the details of method synthesis when using `atomic`).

---

It appears you are confusing "class" and "instance".  Everything in your code points to instances of this and that and you are trying to do something like `this.that.something` where `something` is failing?

The problem is that you are using `@class` to forward declare the class reference.  Basically, until the full class definition is seen by the compiler, any expression like `Foo *` where the compiler has only seen `@class Foo;` acts like a generic reference to an instance of a class of unspecified type (kind of like, but not quite, `id`).

You need to #import the files containing the declarations of your classes.   Think of it in terms of compiler visibility.  When you compile the file that has the dot syntax expression, consider *the exact set of declarations the compiler has seen prior to that expression being compiled*.   If the `@interface` for the class hasn't been seen, you can't use dot syntax on an instance of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Having an ivar is not enable for dot-syntax to work. You need to make it a *property* by adding

```
@property(retain) NSString* myString;
```

to the @interface, and

```
@synthesize myString;
```

to the @implementation.

Basically, the getter dot syntax `abc.efg` can be translated to `[abc efg]`. But to access an ivar you use the syntax `abc->efg`, which is a totally different concept. See [“Declared Properties”](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1) for detail.

Comment: hmmm,
I have both @property and @synthesize.
I tried the whole -> but I got a pointer error. I guess I should just read the link you posted.

Comment: You don't need an @property to access something via the dot syntax.

Comment: Using `abc->efg` is generally considered poor form. Please write accessors (or `@synthesize` some with a property).

Comment: it turns out I hadnt imported "class B" in my main UIVIEW .. I assumed I wouldnt need to because it was imported in "class A"
dumb ...da dumb da dumb
.
Thanks for all the feedback!