# Why should I do @synthesize myProp = _myProp? And why call it with self. in front?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I notice that some samples of code using the following syntax:

```
@synthesize myProp = _myProp;
```

How is that different than just doing this?

```
@synthesize myProp;
```

And later in the code they call it by doing this:

```
self.myProp = xyz;
```

Why not just call it this way?

```
mpProp = xyz;
```

Can someone explain the differences?

Comment: @CodaFi - I know what they DO... I am asking what the different syntax is for... one vs the other. Your "duplicate" is not a duplicate of this question.

Comment: Property access syntax is covered in the ObjC language spec from Apple and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297646/how-does-dot-syntax-work-in-objective-c).

Comment: Calling with `self.` calles the setter/getter method, directly accessing the ivar (`_myProp = ...`) does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to your question.

### Part 1:

Using `self.myProp = xyz` calls the setter of the property to set the data, instead of direct assigning `myProp = xyz`. It's advised to access and modify data, even private or internal data, by setters and getters. They give you a way of handling related issues with the data as @SplinterReality mentioned in his answer. But the related issues can be more than that, for example:

**Lazy loading**

```
- (SomeObject *) myProp {
    if(_myprop == nil) {
        _myProp = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
    }
    return _myProp;
}
```

**Doing some related actions** Note: This can also be handled by KVO. This is simpler.

```
- (void) setProperty:(SomeObject *)object (
    _property = object;
    id relatedProperty = //Contruct related value here.
    self.relatedProperty = relatedProperty;
    [self updateViewThatShowsPropertyContent];
}
```

---

### Part 2:

Using `@synthesize` is used to create the default setters and getters of the property, i.e. you're not going to provide your custom implementation for them.

`@synthesize myProp = variableName;` makes the generated instance variable named `_variableName`. But the default behavior is generating an instance variable called `_property` for `@property property`. So `@synthesize myProp = _myProp;` and `@synthesize myProp;` aren't different.

**However**, in modern Objective-C used right now, `@synthezie` is not needed, i.e. it's called for you. So unless you need to provide an instance variable other than the default name, you don't need to call it.

Answer (score 3):

The main advantage of doing this is that you're using getters and setters when accessing the properties. This is important because:

- Setters manage memory semantics automatically, retaining and releasing object references automatically.
- Automatically get you KVO semantics, which is important in several different contexts

The first reason is less important with ARC, but the latter is still a pretty large benefit.

Comment: It is not necessary to even use `@synthesize` anymore, the compiler now automatically creates the ivar and setter/getter in the manner the OP wrote. i.e.: @synthesize myProp = _myProp;`